# PHP Form Pull From Remote XML

Tags: php, xml, forms

I have a php form that users submit their start / end dates. The form then needs to pull the results from .xml hosted on a different URL. The URL varies based on the dates entered by the user - dates become part of the URL as you can see below.

So, simply put... The user enters the dates. It calls the xml file via the URL (which changes slightly as the dates are entered into that URL) and it displays the results on a new page.

I would rather do it via PHP than AJAX if possible.

This is the frontend of my form:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="test_get.php" method="get">
Start Date: <input type="text" id="start" name="start"><br>
End Date: <input type="text" id="end" name="end"> <br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is 'test_get.php':

```
<html>
<body>

<form onSubmit="return process();">
Start Date: <?php echo $_GET["start"]; ?><br>
End Date: <?php echo $_GET["end"]; ?>
    </form>
</body>

<script>
function process()
{
var url="http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug," + document.getElementById("start").value + "," + document.getElementById("end").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>

</html>
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried this:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug," + document.getElementById("start").value + "," + document.getElementById("end").value"); or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo $xml->field . "<br>";
echo $xml->data . "<br>";
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

But again, no luck. Can anyone see what i'm missing?

I can also share what my .xml form looks like if needed. Any help is greatly appreciated - i've been tackling this for days! Thanks! :)

UPDATE: This is my updated code for test_get.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$url = '"http://69.239.118.197:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug,'.$_GET['start'].','.$_GET['end'].'"';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo $xml->field . "<br>";
echo $xml->data . "<br>";
echo var_dump($xml). "<br />";
?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your primary goal? I'm slightly confused by what you are doing...

Comment: I'm trying to display the data from the .xml file based on what the user has entered (dates).

Comment: So the user enters the dates. It calls the xml file via the URL (which changes slightly as the dates are entered into that URL) and it displays the results on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last block of code that you posted, you are using JavaScript outside of script tags, so this is definitely not going to work. Have you tried instead putting your $_GET variable into the query string?

Note* I pulled out the query string for more readability. It's hard for me to verify that this is working for you outside of your environment, but give it a shot.

You've got this:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug," + document.getElementById("start").value + "," + document.getElementById("end").value"); or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

I'm recommending this:

```
$url = '"http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug,'.$_GET['start'].','.$_GET['end'].'"';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

*************EDIT*****************

So, after attempting to manipulate the data that `simplexml_load_file` returns I decided to try `file_get_contents`. The solution below returns the data value from the xml file in string format.

```
$_GET['start'] = '08/30/2017';
$_GET['end'] = '08/31/2017';

$xml = file_get_contents("http://69.239.118.197:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug,".$_GET['start'].','.$_GET['end'].'"');

echo $xml;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Am not sure what you mean by this: "Have you tried instead putting your $_GET variable into the query string?". I did change to the code you provided and I still get a blank page. No errors.

Comment: Have you tried using 'var_dump($xml)'? What is it outputting?

Comment: Yep, with that I get:  bool(false)

Comment: I even tried putting the exact URL in there (i.e. http://99.999.999.999:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug,08/30/2017,08/31/2017) and it comes back with the same response. So it doesn't seem like it's calling it right. If I put that URL into a browser directly, it will give me the XML data.

Comment: Is the data here private? Can you provide the url?

Comment: Sure. I don't think it will hurt, it's possibly a problem caused by what i'm telling it to "echo". This is the URL: http://69.239.118.197:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug,08/30/2017,08/31/2017  (I put some dates in there so that you actually get data)

Comment: I just updated my original post too, to include the updated code with the changes you have suggested.

Comment: I think it's to do with the way the URL is called. If I use $url = "http://69.239.118.197:81/fmi/xml/fmresultset.xml?-db=Front_Desk&-lay=WebRoomQuery&-findany&-script=WebQueryPSOS&-script.param=snug,08/30/2017,08/31/2017";   it works. Perhaps the variable data is the problem?

Comment: I'm thinking that your xml file is too complicated for the php function. I used 'file_get_contents' instead and was able to retrieve the data value. I'm adding my solution to my answer.

Comment: Awesome; THANK YOU!! For some reason I get the data twice, any idea why this might be? I'm going to mark your answer as correct anyway since you have found a solution. Thank you SO much!!!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151317/discussion-between-jase-and-ivcatalina).